# Eclipse changes my font size back to 10 after I changed it to 12

Tags: java, eclipse

I use the preference dialog to change the editor text to 12.
When I quit eclipse and restart it,
the text is drawn at size 12, but after a second or two, it gets drawn at size 10 and I have to change it again.
Is there a way to change the text size so it stays at that size?

Comment: Is it the same if you create a brand-new project?

Comment: Which preference are you changing, and which editor are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

One way is `Goto Windows-> Preference -> General -> Color and Fonts`

And other is

`Cltr and +` will increase the font size
`Cltr and -` will decrease font size.